# How could I keep the same length between ticks in symlog plots?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I made a symlog plot because I would like to plot in logarithmic scale while some quantities are negative. But the y axis ticks are messed up. The length between the ticks is not the same. this is the code I have written to plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
import uncertainties
from uncertainties import ufloat
from uncertainties.umath import *
import uncertainties.unumpy as unp

ANISO_POLY=['2','3','4','5']
ST_INT=['3','4','5']
for st in ST_INT:
        j=0
        rc('text', usetex=True)
        rc('font', family='serif')
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ax.set_xscale('symlog')
        ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthreshy=0.004)

        for aniso in ANISO_POLY:
            correlationGalStarfile='/ST_INTEG_LIM.'+st+'.ANIS_POLY_ORD.'+aniso+'/xi.resample.cat'
            cor=np.loadtxt(correlationGalStarfile)
            Theta=cor[:,0]
            GSPlus=cor[:,1];GSPlusErr=cor[:,5]
            correlationStarfile='ST_INTEG_LIM.'+st+'.ANIS_POLY_ORD.'+aniso+'/xi.cat'
            scor=np.loadtxt(correlationfile)
            SSPlus=scor[:,1];SSPlusErr=scor[:,5]
            GSC = unp.uarray(GSPlus, GSPlusErr)
            SSC = unp.uarray(SSCorPlus, SSPlusErr)
            ratio=GSC*abs(GSC)/SSC
            ErrorXi=unp.std_devs(ratio)
            Xi=unp.nominal_values(ratio)
            ax.errorbar(Theta, Xi, yerr=ErrorXi,  fmt='-', color=colors[j], ecolor=colors[j],  capsize=2, capthick=None,label='aniso. poly. ord. '+aniso)
            j+=1

        ax.set_xlabel(r'$\Theta$', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_ylabel(r'$\xi^{+}_{sys}$', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_title('stellar integration limit '+st)
        ax.set_ylim(-5e-4,5e-4)
        ax.set_yticks((-1e-4,-1e-5,0.0,1e-5,1e-4))
        ax.set_yticklabels([r'$-10^{-4}$',r'$-10^{-5}$' , r'$0.0$', r'$10^{-5}$',r'$10^{-4}$'])

        fontsize=15
        for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
            tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)
        for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
            tick.label1.set_fontsize(fontsize)            
        leg=plt.legend(numpoints=1,loc='upper right', ncol=1,fontsize=15)
        leg.draw_frame(False)
        plotfile='Correlation.SIL.'+st+'.pdf'
        plt.savefig(plotfile, dpi=50, bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.close()
```

The output plot looks like this:
[image]

How could I define the distance between ticks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the `linthreshy` that you specified.

If you specify a linear threshold that includes your tick locations, then you'll see the effect of the linear scale near 0 on your tick locations.

As a quick example of reproducing it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('axes', labelsize=20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xscale='symlog', xlabel=r'$\Theta$', ylabel=r'$\xi^{+}_{sys}$')
ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthreshy=0.004)
ax.set_yticks([-1e-4, -1e-5, 0.0, 1e-5, 1e-4])
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)

ax.axis([1e-1, 1e2, -10**-3.5, 10**-3.5])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

And if we just change `linthreshy` to be smaller than the tick locations that you're manually specifying, you won't see the effect of the linear scale.  The only difference in this code is `linthreshy=1e-5`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('axes', labelsize=20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xscale='symlog', xlabel=r'$\Theta$', ylabel=r'$\xi^{+}_{sys}$')
ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthreshy=1e-5)
ax.set_yticks([-1e-4, -1e-5, 0.0, 1e-5, 1e-4])
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)

ax.axis([1e-1, 1e2, -10**-3.5, 10**-3.5])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]